# Como detectar evento de download nas tags audio e video?

Tags: jquery, html5-audio, html5-video

Tenho o seguinte código num ficheiro JS, o qual uso para detectar quando alguém faz "play" ou "download" de ficheiros áudio e vídeo.

```
$("audio").on("play",     function() {...}); # Funciona
$("video").on("play",     function() {...}); # Funciona
$("audio").on("download", function() {...}); # Não funciona
$("video").on("download", function() {...}); # Não funciona
```

No entanto, no caso do "download" o código não funciona.

Existe alguma maneira de detectar quando alguém faz "download" desses ficheiros?

Answer (score 1):

Existem maneiras sim, porém pelo que pesquisei, nenhuma solução aparenta ser tão trivial quanto capturar um evento. Não existe nenhum [evento](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) que detecta se o usuário fez download do áudio/vídeo.

Segue um link bem interessante, mostrando todos estes eventos em funcionamento e suas respectivas propriedades:

- [HTML5 Video Events and API](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)

Sobre como detectar o download não só de um áudio/vídeo mas de um arquivo da página, seguem algumas referências:

- [Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)
- [Detecting the File Download Dialog In the Browser](http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/)